# I'm not able to use static template command inside a block in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

The following template code in django gives error.

```
{% block css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'correlation_search_create.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
```

Error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /search/create/
Invalid block tag on line 4: 'static', expected 'endblock'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/search/create/
Django Version: 1.9a1
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag on line 4: 'static', expected 'endblock'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

at the beginning of the template.

Reference: [Static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/).

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have [loaded the static tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#template-tags) at the top of your template.

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
```

Comment: Yep. Worked. Thanks a lot!